# Yup.string().matches() alternates beween valid and invalid as you are typing

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

Trying to validate a phone number field in Formik using Yup validation schema, but when i use `Yup.string().matches(/^[0-9]*$/g, 'This is not a number')` it consistently alternates between valid and invalid on each change event.

```
    phone: Yup.string()
      .trim()     
      .matches(/^[0-9]*$/g, 'This is not a number')    
  }),
```

input field is of type `tel`. `<Field type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />`

Answer (score 5):

Ok, appears i could have been my RegEx after all that was causing this strange behavior.

- Original regEx: `/^[0-9]*$/g`
- Modified regEx: `/^[\d]*$/g`
- FINAL regEx: `/^\d+$/` <-- This solved the problem.

My regEx  knowledge is limited so i would be happy if somebody could tell me why the two first regEx codes caused the alternating state of validation.

Comment: I had the same issue with the "g" modifier, no idea why though